# Why I can't type: BlockingQueue<Integer> a = new PriorityQueue<>(2);

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue, blockingqueue

The code I type in title doesn't compile. It says: `Cannot infer arguments`.

After that I did `BlockingQueue<Integer> a = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(2);` which compiles just fine. What was my mistake, so I can avoid it next time?

Yes, I know that constructor in `Queue` interface has parameter(2) for **initial capacity**, while in `BlockingQueue` parameter(2) represents **max elements**. Does this have anything to do with the **error**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for starters, `PriorityQueue` is not a `BlockingQueue`. It wont be able to infer any generic arguments for `PriorityQueue<T>` because there is no `T` that will be valid. That being said, `Cannot infer arguments` sounds like it may be due to a side effect of this change somewhere else in your code.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for `BlockingQueue`, you should instead use one of the classes under "All Known Implementing Classes:", find a library with `BlockingQueue`s, or implement your own.

Your other option is to use another type of queue instead, like `AbstractQueue<Integer>` in place of `BlockingQueue<Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the title doesn't compile because `PriorityQueue` does not implement nor extend `BlockingQueue`. It's like doing this: `LinkedList<Integer> ls = new ArrayList<>():`, which will not compile.